# Building libc (newlib) results in "cannot find -lc"

Tags: c, linker, static-libraries, autoconf

I built a cross-compiler for `sh3eb-elf` targets. Now I need a libc implementation. However, when I want to build [newlib](https://sourceware.org/newlib/), `configure` fails.

Running configure:

`../newlib-cygwin/configure --host=sh3eb-elf`

It fails. A quick look into `config.log`:

```
configure:4435: sh3eb-elf-gcc    conftest.c  >&5
[...]/sh3eb-elf/sh3eb-elf/lib/gcc/sh3eb-elf/8.1.0/../../../../sh3eb-elf/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
configure:4439: $? = 1
```

Obviously the linker does not find **libc** which is what I am trying to build here in the first place. I am confused... Are the parameters of `configure` wrong?

Comment: I am pretty sure that i do not need `--target=`, am I right?

Comment: I successfully completed a build containing `--target=sh3eb-elf` in every `configure` invocation I typed using the pre-packaged tools in Arch Linux: binutils, bootstrapped gcc, newlib with `--target` instead of `--host`, and finally the full gcc. Didn't test whether execution worked, but it compiled a simple `printf("%s\n", "Hello world!");` program. It does seem strange to me that `--target` was required instead of `--host`. Out of curiosity, I tried using `--host` after the full build of GCC, but it didn't seem to do anything other than create the directory I specified with `--prefix`.

Comment: Yeah, meanwhile I reset my setup and tried `--target`... voilà. Strange indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why, but as Chrono Kitsune pointed out, using `--target=sh3eb-elf` does the trick.